# Why do I get “number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length”

Tags: r, matrix, replace, items

I am creating a matrix, eat_matrix, with info from other files. I have created my rows as dive numbers and my column as the prey capture number. Yet with the following script I get the error:

> Error in eat_matrix[dive_no[cols == cls], cls] <- stat[,cols == cls] : 
>     number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Script:

```r
for(cls in 1:ncol(eat_matrix)){
  eat_matrix[dive_no[cols == cls],cls] <- stat[cols == cls]
}
```

I can see it means a mismatch in length, but I don't understand how to fix this. Can anyone help? Thank you!

Edited: this is the code for stat

```
tst <- is.na(dive_no)tst <- is.na(dive_no)
dive_no <- dive_no[!tst]
cols <- cols[!tst]
prey_notInDive <- prey[tst,]

eat_matrix <- matrix(nrow=nrow(dives),ncol=max(len))
stat <- prey$max_Stat[!tst]
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example.  What is `stat`, is it a matrix?  Then you may need the `,` for row,column index separation

Comment: Hi Akrun. I have added the code for stat above. I tried adding the , and still received the same mesage.

Comment: not possible to reproduce your data set. what is `dive_no`, what is `eat_matrix`??

Comment: No worries. Managed to fix this problem by correcting column name mistakes. Thanks anyways!